# SlickGrid get grid instance with jQuery through HTML element

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

My Example: https://jsfiddle.net/djL5ad7m/

My example shows a basic [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) example.
I am creating the Grid like so:

```
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

This *grid* variable is what I am interested in.
[image]

I want to get exactly this element via **jQuery** - so I can call an external function and get the same Grid variable that my code above saves into *"var grid"*.

I have tried to get it like `$('#myGrid').data('Slickgrid')` but that does not work.

(Kendo UI Grid illustrates this perfectly - [see my example with it here](https://dojo.telerik.com/EwOZUsoC/2) and find code below)

```
/***** getGridExternalFunction *****/
  function getGridExternal(){
    var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
    console.log('grid', grid);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SlickGrid doesn't attach itself to the HTML like that, although I have seen that as a standard pattern in some javascript client side controls.
That said, it's easy enough to set this up yourself using jQuery:

```
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
$('#myGrid').data('SlickGrid', grid);
```

the you can retrieve it elsewhere in your code as you have shown:

```
var grid = $('#myGrid').data('SlickGrid');
```

There's a bit of a warning bell regarding your error message though: "cannot read property 'data' of null" would imply that `$('#myGrid')` is returning null, which it shouldn't be if the DOM element myGrid is present. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: As to the error message - due to jsfiddle I had to select the proper "html container" (if that makes sence) in order to "see" the element. I have updated the screenshot in my answer accordingly

Comment: It also looks like you're using the old MLeibman repo. Check out www.slickgrid.net and github.com/6pac/SlickGrid

Answer (score 0):

Get table body data:

```
$('#myGrid').find('.slick-viewport')
```

Get HTML body data:

```
$('#myGrid').find('.slick-viewport')[0].innerHTML
```

To get header data use `.slick-header` in selector.

Comment: Sorry no. I want the element as shown above in the "dark" screenshot of the chrome console